# How to specific number of images included in image_picker using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I fetch multiple images from the gallery and display them to the user. Now the user can fetch an unlimited number of images. I need to make a restriction or limit on the number of images that the user can import and choose, for example, only four images, and no more image can be inserted. How can do that?

I am using the following library: image_picker

```
// Pick multiple images
    final List<XFile>? images = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
```

Full code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image Picker Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Image Picker Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<XFile> _imageFileList;

  set _imageFile(XFile value) {
    _imageFileList = value == null ? null : [value];
  }

  dynamic _pickImageError;
  bool isVideo = false;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();


  void _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource source,
      {BuildContext context, bool isMultiImage = false}) async {
   if (isMultiImage) {

            try {
              final pickedFileList = await _picker.pickMultiImage(
                maxWidth: 66,
                maxHeight: 66,
                imageQuality: 66,
              );
              setState(() {
                _imageFileList = pickedFileList;
              });
            } catch (e) {
              setState(() {
                _pickImageError = e;
              });
            }



    }
  }





  Widget _previewImages() {


    if (_imageFileList != null) {
      return Semantics(
          child: ListView.builder(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Semantics(
                label: 'image_picker_example_picked_image',
                child: kIsWeb
                    ? Image.network(_imageFileList[index].path)
                    : Image.file(File(_imageFileList[index].path)),
              );
            },
            itemCount: _imageFileList.length,
          ),
          label: 'image_picker_example_picked_images');
    } else if (_pickImageError != null) {
      return Text(
        'Pick image error: $_pickImageError',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    } else {
      return const Text(
        'You have not yet picked an image.',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }


  Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
    final LostDataResponse response = await _picker.retrieveLostData();
    if (response.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    if (response.file != null) {
      if (response.type == RetrieveType.video) {
        isVideo = true;

      } else {
        isVideo = false;
        setState(() {
          _imageFile = response.file;
          _imageFileList = response.files;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: !kIsWeb && defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
            ? FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: retrieveLostData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return const Text(
                  'You have not yet picked an image.',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                );
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return _previewImages();
              default:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text(
                    'Pick image/video error: ${snapshot.error}}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Text(
                    'You have not yet picked an image.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  );
                }
            }
          },
        )
            : _previewImages(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                isVideo = false;
                _onImageButtonPressed(
                  ImageSource.gallery,
                  context: context,
                  isMultiImage: true,
                );
              },
              heroTag: 'image1',
              tooltip: 'Pick Multiple Image from gallery',
              child: const Icon(Icons.photo_library),
            ),
          ),



        ],
      ),
    );
  }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the List that holds the images  which is in your case _imageFileList to hold not more than the number of images you need. You can change the method _previewImages to

Widget _previewImages() {

```
if (_imageFileList != null && !_imageFileList.length>4  ) {
  return Semantics(
      child: ListView.builder(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Semantics(
            label: 'image_picker_example_picked_image',
            child: kIsWeb
                ? Image.network(_imageFileList[index].path)
                : Image.file(File(_imageFileList[index].path)),
          );
        },
        itemCount: _imageFileList.length,
      ),
      label: 'image_picker_example_picked_images');
} else if (_pickImageError != null) {
  return Text(
    'Pick image error: $_pickImageError',
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  );
} else {
  return const Text(
    'You have not yet picked an image.',
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  );
}
```

}